# How to get ViewBag change after POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a single page web app using ASP.NET MVC with C# and the controller code is as followed below.

It only has two controllers, a get Index action and a post Contact action. The Contact action is for the contact form I have at the bottom of my page.

Here is what happens. When the page runs the ViewBag.Contact displays on the title of my contact form as it should. When I submit the form and POST the view bag remains unchanged. I am assuming this is because my contact controller does not have a return View() but a return Redirect("#Contact")

I need the Redirect in place so the page appears to not move or change anywhere except in the ViewBag.Contact as the title.

I can get the ViewBag to work if I used return View(). However it will load the page again from the very top of the page and not the bottom where the form is located to make it appear that the page did not reload.

My question is this, is there a way to get the ViewBag to work without reloading the page or moving from where the user is located on the form?

(I know I can accomplish this with other scripting such as javascript but I'd like to use C# ASP.Net as much as possible)

Thank you

```
namespace MySite.MVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {            
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Contact = "SEND ME AN EMAIL BY FILLING OUT THE FORM";
            return View();                               
        }                    

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contact(ContactModels c)
        {                
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {    
                using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("FakeEmail@gmail.com", "password");

                    string body = string.Format(
                        "First Name: {0}\nLast Name: {1}\nEmail: {2}\nComment: {3}",
                        c.FirstName,
                        c.LastName,
                        c.Email,
                        c.Comment
                    );

                    var message = new MailMessage();
                    message.To.Add("SendingEmail@gmail.com");
                    message.From = new MailAddress(c.Email, c.Name);
                    message.Subject = String.Format("Contact Request From: {0} ", c.Name);
                    message.Body = body;
                    message.IsBodyHtml = false;
                    try
                    {
                        client.Send(message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return View("Error");
                    }    
                }                    
            }

            ViewBag.Contact = "THANKS, I'VE RECEIVED YOUR MESSAGE";
            return Redirect("#Contact");                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **no**:

- you can't update a `ViewBag` without reloading the page.
- you can't update a `ViewBag` and show it on the same page.

`ViewBags` are set and live for one request, so, if you set the `ViewBag` in a page (or in a controller behind it), you can show it if you make another HTTP request (open another page or refresh the current one).

You can accomplish what you need by other means (Ajax, Javascript, PartialViews)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is how to render a 'Partial View.' You will end up using AJAX and JS however if you want to do only partial page reload, but the framework can build most of this for you. Here are some good examples:

http://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1883187.aspx?How+to+update+Partial+View+with+doing+a+submit](http://forums.asp.net/t/1883187.aspx?How%20to%20update%20Partial%20View%20with%20doing%20a%20submit)